# Enviar imagen Base64 a un servidor nodejs mediante fetch

Tags: javascript, html5, nodejs, javascript-objeto, javascript-import

Tengo una imagen en formato *Base64* y quiero enviarla a un servidor mediante `fetch` ,pero el servidor no recibe nada.

He intentando usar `blob`, pero sigue sin recibir nada el servidor.

Gracias de antemano

Acá ya obtengo la imagen en Base64.

```js
  let foto = $canvas.toDataURL(); //Esta es la foto, en base 64
  fetch(foto)
  .then(res => res.blob())
  .then(blob => {
    var fd = new FormData();
    const file = new File([blob], "filename.jpeg");
    fd.append('image', file);
    fetch('http://localhost:3000/registreFotos',
      {
        method: 'post',
        body: fd,
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
        }
      })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(res => console.log(res));
  });

  let enlace = document.createElement("a"); // Crear un <a>
  enlace.download = "foto_me.png";
  enlace.href = foto;
  // var formData = new FormData();
  // formData.append('imagen_Data', foto);
  enlace.click();
  document.getElementById('id01').style.display = 'none';
  // openCamara.style.background = "yellow";
  // $video.play();
});
},
(error) => {
  console.log("Permiso denegado o error: ", error);
}
);
};
})();
});
</script>
</html>
```

Este es el archivo principal del servidor:

[image: Este es el código por parte del servidor]

Comment: Falta información del lado del servidor, ¿cómo analizas el cuerpo de la solicitud? ¿estás habilitando la recepción de datos tipo `multipart`?

Comment: @MauricioContreras esa recepcion de datos tupo multipart se debe habilitar en el servidor ?

Comment: @RicardoTovar se debe habilitar en la peticion que haces, al parecer ya pusiste lo del multipart, sin embargo lo importante en este caso es mirar como estas tratando de recibir o corroborar si recibiste efectivamente la imagen en el servidor, toca que pongas el codigo del lado de nodejs con el que miras eso.

Comment: @Riven justamente eso , en consola de front me llega la imagen en base 64 , pero al enviarlo al servidor y hacer un console.log req.body , me sale vacio

Comment: En tu servidor NodeJS necesitas configurar un middleware para analizar el cuerpo de la solicitud. Uno de los más populares para recibir datos es [`multer`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer). Saludos

Comment: @MauricioContreras pero a mi ruta si pongo req.body al menos no me deberia salir algo del front?

Comment: quiero saber si mi front esta bien , para ver solo lo del servidor

Comment: Pues no tienes analizador (*parser*) configurado, por lo que se aprecia. Puedes usar los que expone Express: `app.use(express.json());` y `app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));`. Con eso al menos verás los campos del formulario en el objeto `body` de la solicitud. Pero para trabajar con archivos necesitas `multer` o alguna otra librería. Saludos

Comment: Para ver los datos que envías en la solicitud puedes usar la consola del navegador. A simple vista el `front` se ve bien.

Comment: @MauricioContreras si el front creo q si,ademas ese string q me devolvio lo puse en una pagina q convertirtia de base 64 a png , y si mostraba

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111571/discussion-between-mauricio-contreras-and-ricardo-tovar).